# Aspnet Zero Time on client side is incorrect when daylight saving is on

Tags: timezone, momentjs, aspnetboilerplate, dst, aspnetzero

In **AspNet Zero Core + Angular Project**. I have Set **Clock Provider to UTC** `Clock.Provider = ClockProviders.Utc;` in Startup.cs
as stated in the document which causes timezone selection in settings for user and Tenant Settings and saves UTC dates in db.

Problem is these Days 30th Oct 2020, **MST** (Mountain Standard Time) is observing **Daylight Saving** but times on the angular project is not respecting that its showing one hours difference...

One possible Option Scenario is to Select MDT instead of MST but that's not available in Timezone Dropdown in aspnetzero as its using windows timezones...
anyone ever managed to deal with this issue?

**PS**:In their support articles they claim that it should be automatically handeled by momentjs but its not... Maybe i'm missing somthing?

Comment: The Windows time zone with the ID `"Mountain Standard Time"` has this display name `"(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)"` and represents *both* MST and MDT.  Pretend it just says "Mountain Time" and it will make sense.  As for the behavior you described, you'll need to show some us code reproducing the problem.  Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question to add supporting details.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, could the problem possibly be that you've selected `"US Mountain Standard Time"`?  That one is for Arizona, which does not use daylight saving time.  (Don't be fooled by the "US" in the front, it only applies to Arizona.)